# How do you safely renew a distribution certificate?

Tags: ios, keychain

We're a small organization and just noticed some iOS provisioning profiles expired. While working through that, we discovered our iOS distribution certificate is going to expire soon as well.

Thanks to problems incurred by pandemic protocols, fixing that isn't going well. We're suspicious the private key is on a computer in the office. Someone's headed that way to investigate while I'm trying to think about backup plans. I'm confused and flustered because I can't seem to find information about what happens if we can't find the private key.

So I need to know:

- What happens when the distribution certificate expires? Will it affect customers?
- What happens if I generate a new distribution certificate and revoke the old one? Will it affect customers?
- If those are disasters, how do I safely handle this?

I can't seem to find information about either of these I trust.

Comment: Did you read this? https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/